# testing component with ng-container in DOM Angular , Karma fails?

Tags: html, angular, karma-jasmine

Hello I have a component which display a sub-menu like to the right this:
[image]

the html code is below

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<ng-container  *ngFor="let link of links">
  <a class="vsk__button-link" [ngClass]="{'vsk__is-active': isActive(link.route)}" [routerLink]="link.route" routerLinkActive="true" *ngIf="containsRoles(link.roles)">
    <label>{{link.page}}</label>
  </a>
</ng-container>
```

As you can see I'm displaying links which comes from property binding.
And the problem is that when I'm launching the test my DOM sees only  mark-up whose innerHtml is void and ng-container don't appear. Does it mean that I should create other components which till I'm allowed to access this 3 links?

for instance this is my code in karma spec.ts

```js
 beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SubMenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    adminFixture.detectChanges();

  });

  it('should create ng-container', () => {
    expect(fixture.debugElement.children[1].children).toBeTruthy();
  });
```